# How to call $scope.closePopup on click in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I created the popup when I am trying to call action on click for close pop up icon no change is shown.

In index.html in bottom there is code for pop up, this will be shown when user will click on change zip code link.

```
<!-- Pop up div -->
    <div class="popup" ng-show="myModal" ng-controller="utilityCtrl">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="popup-content">
          <span class="close" ng-click="closePopup">×</span>
        <div class="dynamicContect" id="dynamicContect"> Loading ...
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

      <!-- html of change zip code -->

    <div class="hidden" id="updateZipContent">
        <div class="zipContent">
            <div class="padding-bt-2">Please enter new zip code</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="text-left col-md-6 padding-bt-2">
                        <input ng-model="zipCode" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" data-required="true" number-only>
                </div>  
                <div class="text-left col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary form-control">Update</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Change zip code action is written in autoQuotectrl.js

```
$scope.changeZipCode = function()
                    {
                        $rootScope.myModal = true;
                        var firstDivContent = document.getElementById('updateZipContent');
                        var secondDivContent = document.getElementById('dynamicContect');
                        secondDivContent.innerHTML = firstDivContent.innerHTML;                        
                    }
```

To keep other action separate I wrote new controller utilityCtrl.js.
Here I wrote action for hide this popup .

```
$scope.closePopup = function ()
        {
            console.log('here in utility');
            $rootScope.myModal = false;
            document.getElementById('dynamicContect').innerHTML = "";
        }
```

But nothing is working, please help me to understand what I am missing here.
It seems $rootScope.myModal is not accessible in utilityCtrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't invoke function `closePopup` in template.

See example on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MTOy199IHJmPtF86JrYw?p=preview).

```
  <div class="popup" ng-show="myModal" ng-controller="utilityCtrl">
    <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="popup-content">
        <span class="close" ng-click="closePopup()">×</span>
        <div class="dynamicContect" id="dynamicContect"> Loading ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I am trying as well to call validate for required on input box of popup and show error below input box. can please suggest how to do this.

Comment: You need to create a new post. You can not create a few questions for one post.

Comment: posted new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219932/how-to-validate-input-without-form-tag-in-angular-js, please suggest me the way to set validation.

Answer (score 0):

they are in two controller,so the $scope is diferent ,you can use $rootScope.$broadcast and $scope.$on