# How to validate input without form tag in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

In popup I am showing html which I copy from another div and show in popup.
Here I want to validate this input field for required. and show error message below input box. 
 index.html

    
      
      
          ×
         Loading ...

```
  <!-- html of change zip code -->

<div class="hidden" id="updateZipContent">
    <div class="zipContent">
        <div class="padding-bt-2">Please enter new zip code</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-left col-md-6 padding-bt-2">
                    <input ng-model="zipCode" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" data-required="true" number-only>
            </div>  
            <div class="text-left col-md-4">
                <button class="btn btn-primary form-control">Update</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Change zip code action is written in autoQuotectrl.js

```
$scope.changeZipCode = function()
                    {
                        $rootScope.myModal = true;
                        var firstDivContent = document.getElementById('updateZipContent');
                        var secondDivContent = document.getElementById('dynamicContect');
                        secondDivContent.innerHTML = firstDivContent.innerHTML;                        
                    }
```

To keep other action separate I wrote new controller utilityCtrl.js. Here I wrote action for hide this popup .

```
$scope.closePopup = function ()
        {
            console.log('here in utility');
            $rootScope.myModal = false;
            document.getElementById('dynamicContect').innerHTML = "";
        }
```

How to set validation here?
https://plnkr.co/edit/aV65Nab9U9I6YlK2g4sY?p=preview

Comment: why xan't you se the form tag ?

Comment: Can't you use `ng-form` directive too?

Comment: I can put div class="zipContent"> .. inside a form tag but when I will copy this in popup, then same form will be repeated.

Comment: Show `html` template for popup.

Comment: You will probably have to [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) the HTML you cloned to make it work in angular way with bindings and directives. `form` tag is not a requirement for `validation` as validation directives are applied to elements directly.

Comment: Validation working without `form`. But it is impossible to know the **validation error** and show it.

Comment: @sabithpocker I am not geting how to do this. can you please suggest with some code changes.

Comment: How to move this popup content <div class="hidden" id="updateZipContent">.. to directive and show in pop up when clicking on change zip code link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/25apIEoqQ8J8b8d3qsIw).

We can use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) directive.

```
$scope.changeZipCode = function()
                {
                    $rootScope.myModal = true;
                    var firstDivContent = document.getElementById('updateZipContent');
                    var secondDivContent = document.getElementById('dynamicContect');
                    var clonedElement = $compile(firstDivContent.innerHTML)($scope, function(clonedElement, scope) {
                      //attach the clone to DOM document at the right place
                      secondDivContent.innerHTML ="";
                      angular.element(secondDivContent).append(clonedElement);
                  });                        
                }
```

Comment: this looks good, validation error should be shown when user click on button. not on popup load.

Comment: I'm update [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/25apIEoqQ8J8b8d3qsIw?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-form="myForm">
      <input type="text" required ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Username">
      
      <button ng-click="doSomething()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">DO</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: update plunker with code, but its not working for me.